# Execute dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() from xctest

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I am trying to write test, that stubs the requests with OHHTTPStubs and then it should load the UI. The stub part is working, but the problem is, that test and UI loading are both executed on the main thread, so this block of loading ViewController never gets executed. Thanks for the tips in advance. Have a great day.

```
dispatch_block_t mainBlock = ^{
        WDSomeVC *viewController = [[WDSomeVC alloc] initWithData:data andStyle:self.style];
        viewController.delegate = self;
        [self switchRootController:viewController withCompletion:nil];
};
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), mainBlock);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using this code.

```
 [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeToWait]];
```